# Ayuda con un par de cosas en juego snake en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un juego de snake en c#, y necesitaría un par de cosas que no se muy bien como hacer:

> Necesito que el juego mande un mensaje similar a "has muerto" en cuanto la serpiente toque el muro o se toque a si misma, pero antes que esto, necesito saber cómo puedo hacer que la serpiente avance con un tamaño inicial establecido, por ejemplo 2 o 3 anillas

Cabe decir que tengo cierta idea sobre cómo hacer lo del muro, estaba pensando en algo como:

si (abs(cx) == 30 o abs(cy) == 100) entonces te saca del programa

Pero no se si esta sería la forma más correcta, así que si alguien puede darme alguna orientación más, le estaré inmensamente agradecido. Os dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace snake_dia_1
{
    class Program
    {

        public struct Coords
        {
            public int cX;
            public int cY;
        }

        public struct Cuc
        {
            public int cX;
            public int cY;
            //public coords cap; seria mes correcte
            public char direccio;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Cuc cuc = new Cuc();
            bool sortir = false;
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;

            pintaMarc();
            cuc.direccio = 'd';
            pintaCuc(ref cuc.cX, ref cuc.cY);

            while (!sortir)
            { 
                if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                {
                    cki = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                    {
                        cuc.direccio = 'w';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                    {
                        cuc.direccio = 's';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                    {
                        cuc.direccio = 'a';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                    {
                        cuc.direccio = 'd';
                    }
                    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                    {
                        exit();
                    }
                }

                mouCuc(ref cuc.cX, ref cuc.cY, cuc.direccio);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150);

            }


        } //end main()

        static void pintaMarc()
        {
            //caracters marc 186 ║, 187 ╗, 188 ╝, 200 ╚, 201 ╔, 205 ═

            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 1);
            Console.WriteLine("╔");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 30);
            Console.WriteLine("╚");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(100, 1);
            Console.WriteLine("╗");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(100, 30);
            Console.WriteLine("╝");


            for (int y = 2; y < 100; y++)
            {
                int x = 1;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(y, x);
                Console.WriteLine("═");
            }

            for (int x = 2; x < 30; x++)
            {
                int y = 1;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(y, x);
                Console.WriteLine("║");

                y = 100;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(y, x);
                Console.WriteLine("║");
            }

            for (int y = 2; y < 100; y++)
            {
                int x = 30;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(y, x);
                Console.WriteLine("═");
            }


         }

        static void pintaCuc(ref int cx, ref int cy)
        {

            cx = 30;
            cy = 10;

                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("█");
        }

        static void mouCuc(ref int cx, ref int cy, char direccio)
        {
            if(direccio == 'w')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("█");
                cy--;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("0");
            }
            if (direccio == 'a')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("█");
                cx--;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("0");
            }
            if (direccio == 's')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("█");
                cy++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("0");
            }
            if (direccio == 'd')
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("█");
                cx++;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cx, cy);
                Console.Write("0");
            }
        }

        static void exit ()
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

    } //end class
}//end namespace
```

Comment: Con el tema del muro yo guardaria en una variable tipo point la posicion donde se encuentra siempre la cabeza de la serpiente, luego actualizar siempre esta posicion en funcion de donde teclea el usuario y una vez actualizado ver si la posicion tanto X como Y es igual a 0, entonces ha chocado y tambien si X es igual a la longitud maxima o Y es igual a la altura.

Comment: Ya se te ha cerrado una pregunta similar por ser muy amplia. En lugar de abrir otra pregunta similar, edita la primera y añade la información que se te ha solicitado.

Comment: Ok, disculpad, he preferido abrir otra pregunta ya que la otra quedaba cerrada, haciendo unas preguntas diferentes a las que proponía ahí

Comment: Si de verdad son 2 preguntas distintas, está bien. Pero asegúrate de que el título sea más específico. Si no puedes definir un título específico, probablemente indica que la pregunta no es específica tampoco, por lo que acabas con 2 preguntas que tienen el mismo título poco significativo *ayuda con un par de cosas...*.

Comment: @THR4SH3RP0L0, para una próxima ocasión también puedes editar la pregunta y la comunidad votará para la reapertura de la misma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el muro siempre esta en una posición fija lo mejor que puedes hacer es lo que planteas.

```
if (cx>=100 || cy>=30 || cy==0 || cx==0) {
  // Sortir de l'aplicació
}
```

Donde aparecen 100, 30 y 0 deben ser las posiciones absolutas del muro X, Y

Saludos,

Comment: Ok, esto es lo que pensaba con el muro, alguna idea referente a que la serpiente empiece con una longitud determinada y/o que choque con ella misma?

Comment: Para hacer que tenga longitud deberías almacenar todas las posiciones del cuerpo en un array
Cuc[] cuc= new Cuc[MAX_POSICIONES];
hacer un bucle que recorra el array y ir pintando el cuerpo en pantalla despues ir actualizando cada posición a medida que muevas la serpiente.

para verificar si choca contra ella misma debes recorrer el array del cuerpo y comprobar si la primera parte del cuerpo colisiona con alguna del resto de cuerpo.